# Merge an array of objects using key value in lodash?

Tags: node.js, lodash

I'm using node.js and lodash.

I have data like this:

```
[ 
  { 
    to: [ 'foo@bar.com', 'foo1@bar.com' ],
    submittedSubs: [ [Object] ] 
  },
  { 
    to: [ 'foo@bar.com', 'foo2@bar.com' ],
    submittedSubs: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] 
  } 
]
```

I'd like to turn it into data like this where it's "sorted" by `to`

```
[ 
  { 
    to: 'foo@bar.com', 
    submittedSubs: [ [Object],[Object], [Object], [Object] ] 
  },
  { 
    to: 'foo1@bar.com', 
    submittedSubs: [ [Object] ] 
  },
  { 
    to: 'foo2@bar.com',
    submittedSubs: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] 
  }
]
```

How can I do this?

I've tried this:

```
spam[0].to.push('foo@bar.com');  
spam[0].to.push('foo1@bar.com'); 
spam[1].to.push('foo@bar.com');  
spam[1].to.push('foo2@bar.com'); 

console.log('data is',spam);

var byUser=[];
_.each(spam, function(data){
    _.each(data.to,function(addr){
        byUser.push({to:addr,submittedSubs:data.submittedSubs});
    });
});
console.log('attempt',_.merge(byUser));
```

But that gives me this:

```
[ { to: 'foo@bar.com', submittedSubs: [ [Object] ] },
{ to: 'foo1@bar.com', submittedSubs: [ [Object] ] },
{ to: 'foo@bar.com', submittedSubs: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
{ to: 'foo2@bar.com', submittedSubs: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

Comment: seems like the easiest way would be to start by creating an object with the email address as the key, and the value being an array of objects. you can then convert that back into an array and sort it on `to` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll work for you:

```
var unique = {};
byUser.forEach(function(user) {
    unique[user.to] = unique[user.to] || [];
    unique[user.to] = unique[user.to].concat(user.submittedSubs);
});
unique = Object.keys(unique).map(function (key, i) {
    return {to: key, submittedSubs: unique[key]};
});

/*
[ { to: 'foo@bar.com', submittedSubs: [ [Object] ] },
{ to: 'foo1@bar.com', submittedSubs: [ [Object] ] },
{ to: 'foo2@bar.com', submittedSubs: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } ]
*/
```

---

*I stand by that this should be achievable using the callback feature of `_.uniq` but I couldn't get it to work the way you needed it to.*

You should be able to use [`_.uniq`](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq) from [lodash](/questions/tagged/lodash) on your final array:

```
_.uniq(byUser, "to");

/*
[ { to: 'foo@bar.com', submittedSubs: [ [Object] ] },
{ to: 'foo1@bar.com', submittedSubs: [ [Object] ] },
{ to: 'foo2@bar.com', submittedSubs: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } ]
*/
```

Comment: I'd like `foo@bar` to contain four `submittedSubs`, though. One from the first object, and three from the second object. but with this, it only contains one.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine there's some nice `lodash` facilities to shorten this up a bit, but here's a vanilla-js solution:

```
var data = [ 
  { 
    to: [ 'foo@bar.com', 'foo1@bar.com' ],
    submittedSubs: [{ id: 'sub1' }] 
  },
  { 
    to: [ 'foo@bar.com', 'foo2@bar.com' ],
      submittedSubs: [{ id: 'sub2' }, { id: 'sub3' }, { id: 'sub4' }]
  } 
];

var emailSubsMap = data.reduce(function(result, record) {
    record.to.forEach(function(email) {
        result[email] = (result[email] || [])
            .concat(record.submittedSubs);
    });
    return result;
}, {});

var formatted = Object.keys(emailSubsMap).map(function(email) {
    return { to: email, submittedSubs: emailSubsMap[email] };
}).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.to <= b.to ? -1 : 1;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(formatted));
```

(Formatted) console output:

```
[
    {
        "to": "foo1@bar.com",
        "submittedSubs": [
            { "id": "sub1" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "to": "foo2@bar.com",
        "submittedSubs": [
            { "id": "sub2" },
            { "id": "sub3" },
            { "id": "sub4" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "to": "foo@bar.com",
        "submittedSubs": [
            { "id": "sub1" },
            { "id": "sub2" },
            { "id": "sub3" },
            { "id": "sub4" }
        ]
    }
]
```

Note that I mocked up what the `submittedSubs` objects might look like, simply for testing purposes.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vgexn06L/1/)

A couple notes about the sorting:

- My first version wasn't sorting correctly... it's been updated. :)
- The sort method you're requesting doesn't follow JavaScript's "native" string sort order.  E.g., `['foo@bar.com', 'foo2@bar.com', 'foo1@bar.com'].sort() --> ['foo1@bar.com','foo2@bar.com','foo@bar.com']`, so if you really want `foo@bar.com` to come before `foo1@bar.com`, you'll need to define your sort criteria in a little more detail.

Comment: When I run this I get `[TypeError: Object foo@bar.com has no method 'forEach']`

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly? Please refer to the jsfiddle example to see it functioning correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/vgexn06L/1/

Comment: Alternatively, is it possible that not all of your data is shaped like in the example?  E.g., perhaps some of the `to` values are single values instead of arrays?